# JavaScript to Edit HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have used a little bit of JavaScript to change the contents of a paragraph element using a button.  It's working fine, but I want to also have the button control the heading and an accompany picture.  Point me in the right direction?

Here's the code I'm using to change the paragraph

```
<p id="change">....</p>

<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = "..."</button>
```

Thanks!

Comment: so reference the elements and set their content.

Comment: I am trying to do them both in the same button.  Would I do something like: <p id="change">...</p>
<h3 id="change2">...</h3>
<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("change").innerhtml = ".." onclick='document.getElementById("change2".innerhtml=".."></button>

Comment: What do you mean by "control the heading and an accompany picture"?  You need to identify *specifically* what you want your code to do before you can write code to do it.  As it stands the only suggestion I can really think of is to move this one line of in-line JavaScript into a function and call the function from `onclick`.  That way you can easily have multiple lines of code in the function.

Comment: I'm gonna give it a shot, David.  I'll reply in a few with the results/problems!

Comment: so use a semicolon: `document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = "...";document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "..."`

But it would be a lot better if you used a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try separating your JavaScript code into a `<script>` element after your `<body>` to make it easier to manage.Try something like this:

```
<p id="change">Existing Text</p>
<p id="anotherChange">Some Other Existing Text</p>


<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Here!</button>

<script>
    function myFunction(){
        document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = "New Text";
        document.getElementById("anotherChange").innerHTML = "New Text Again";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I just wrote some very similar code.  Going to compare yours to mine and try to get it working!

Comment: @NateMathews Glad to hear it. Please accept this as the answer if it helped.

Comment: I actually can't get your code or mine to work.  Not sure If i'm making a mistake, very new to javascript and programming.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I had a typo. Forgot to declare the function. Please see this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/721k7jqm/

Comment: playing with it right now.  give me a few then I'll declare your answer correct!

Comment: I'm really confused.... I edited my code to match yours and only one of the options changed.   So I copy and pasted your exact code.. and now the other one changes, but the other does not.

Comment: Can you share some code or a jsfiddle to reproduce?

Comment: Got it!  In my previous attempt I had left another paragraph with the same id earlier in the document.  Working now!  Thank you so much for your patience helping me.  Definitely need to hit the books.... how would you recommend I continue learning?  I've been reading the book "Beginning JavaScript by Jeremy McPeak"

Comment: Glad to help. My own journey began here, at the recommendation of a friend: http://javascriptissexy.com/how-to-learn-javascript-properly/. I enjoyed the syllabus-type approach as it gave me steps to follow. Good luck!